# Reg Expression: GB Vat Number with spaces

Tags: regex, html, expression

I currently have the following regular expression:

```
^GB([0-9]{9}([0-9]{3})?|[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3})$
```

This works fine for:

- GB999999973
- GBGD001
- GBHA599

As can be tested here: https://regex101.com/r/jU980W/1

However the problem is that it does not validate with:

- GB999 9999 73

I tried adding space indicators to the regular expression but then the other formats aren't supported anymore.

Does anyone know a way to have this regular expression both accept with and without spaces for the GB VAT Number?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about [`^GB(?:\d{3} ?\d{4} ?\d{2}(?:\d{3})?|[A-Z]{2}\d{3})$`](https://regex101.com/r/jU980W/2)?

Comment: Yep that seems to be doing the trick alright! Feel free to add your answer so I can check it as a valid marked/finished thread! Thanks a bunch for the fast reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/jU980W/2)

```
^GB(?:\d{3} ?\d{4} ?\d{2}(?:\d{3})?|[A-Z]{2}\d{3})$
```

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `GB` Match this literally
- `(?:\d{3} ?\d{4} ?\d{2}(?:\d{3})?|[A-Z]{2}\d{3})` Match either of the following options

  - `\d{3} ?\d{4} ?\d{2}(?:\d{3})?` Option 1:

    - `\d{3}` Match exactly 3 digits
    - `?` Optionally match a space
    - `\d{4}` Match exactly 4 digits
    - `?` Optionally match a space
    - `\d{3}` Match exactly 2 digits
    - `(?:\d{3})?` Optionally match exactly 3 digits
  - `[A-Z]{2}\d{3}` Option 2:

    - `[A-Z]` Match any uppercase ASCII letter
    - `\d{3}` Match exactly 3 digits
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks a bunch for the fast reply and help!